# Problem with Jquery post of special characters

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I was testing my code and am doing a form post using jquery post.  My relevant code is:

```js
$.post('backoffice.aspx', $('form#form1').serialize(), function(data) {
  alert(data)
});
```

I am getting an error in the console saying: POST http://dmdev-server/backoffice/backoffice.aspx 500 (Internal Server Error)

I have a textarea, but does not matter if I use an input field.

If I add some test, it posts fine, but I whittled it down to not working if I out `<input-"source"`

Somehow that in the input box causes it to through that error.  I have even tried posting all special characters but not starting with a `<` and it posts fine.

I added an alert and viewing the serialize data, it looks fine.

Maybe I need to specify a content type? I have tried several iterations and thought maybe someone would know what I need to do.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with your client-side code

Comment: Oh yeah, 500 internal server error.  I should have caught that.  What should I do with this question?

Comment: Still weird.  If I do < it posts, if I do <i it does not.

Comment: It sounds like it posts regardless of what you type. It's your server that handles the request differently based on the payload.